# Getting play-store version of the application

Tags: java, android, app-update

I tried using JSOUP library to get the application version for the play-store website.
But it's not working as google has updated their website structure recently.
I am working on java platform.
What's the best way to get the version of the application.

Answer (score 0):

if your purpose is to provide update control you can use AppUpdateManager. Thanks to AppUpdateManager, you can check if there is an update, show an automatic message to the user and download the update. At the same time, it offers 2 options called IMMEDIATE and FLEXIBLE. With these options, you have the chance to make the update mandatory or optional.

for more : https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateManager

Comment: This method even though officially suggested fails to work on some devices and falsely reports that there's no new update see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188266/error-while-implementing-android-in-app-update